# Is there a good practice to have cron jobs in a spring webflux app?

Tags: aws-lambda, spring-webflux

For a while now, our team started to work on a reactive new micro-service. The service is mainly using **spring-webFlux** and other cool reactive futures.

At this point there should be created a cron-job triggered every 10 secs(that has to verify some transactions state), but I'm afraid that this will affect the load of the app and also is not compatible with the reactive concurrency model since the **@Scheduled** job when will be triggered it's going to consume one thread until it ends.

At this point I'm more in favor of an **aws-lambda** that it's going to call an endpoint of our app.

Do you have any better suggestions or advices ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't schedule an AWS Lambda to run more often than once a minute. If you need an event to occur every 10 seconds in Spring I think using `@Scheduled` is your best option.

Comment: You're right. In the past we've encountered the same issue by lambda frequency limitation, and we've implemented the aws recommended solution: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/a-serverless-solution-for-invoking-aws-lambda-at-a-sub-minute-frequency/ . It solved our problem back then. At this point we can reuse that. But I'm really curious if we can avoid it and see if using @Scheduled with such a high frequency it's a good idea into a reactive context.

Comment: Generally it is not a best practices of using spring schedule, which makes it is hard to scale out your app. If you are using k8s orchestrating your micro service, using k8s Job API is a better alternative.

Comment: @Kane If you use a JDBC JobStore for the scheduler service it should scale fine. Do you have references that show otherwise?